# Implementing Multiple Filters in Fluent UI SearchBox Causes Indefinite Queries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch

I am using Fluent UI's SearchBox component and trying to implement multiple filters. When I used a single filter, it worked fine. However, when I try to implement multiple filters, it goes into an indefinite loop, and multiple queries are called indefinitely.

```
<SearchBox
  styles={searchBoxStyles}
  placeholder="Search Ticket"
  onChange={(event, value) => {
    if (value) {
      setSearchTerm(value.toLocaleLowerCase());
    }
  }}
  onSearch={() => {
    if (selectedFiltersArray && selectedFiltersArray.length > 0 && searchTerm?.trim()) {
      const newFilters = selectedFiltersArray.map((filterTerm: any) => ({
        [filterTerm.value]: { wildcard: `*${searchTerm}*` },
      }));

      setSearchFiltersArray((prev: any) => {
        const updatedFilters = [...prev];
        newFilters.forEach((newFilter: any) => {
          const key = Object.keys(newFilter)[0];
          const index = updatedFilters.findIndex((filterObj) => filterObj[key]);
          if (index === -1) {
            updatedFilters.push(newFilter);
          } else {
            updatedFilters[index] = newFilter;
          }
        });
        return updatedFilters;
      });

      setIsElasticSearchQueryEnabled(true);
    }
  }}
  onClear={() => {
    setSelectedFilter(null);
    setSelectedFiltersArray(null);
    setSearchFilters({});
    setIsElasticSearchQueryEnabled(false);
    setSearchTerm(null);
  }}
/>
```

In the onSearch event, I am checking if selectedFiltersArray is not null and has at least one element, and if searchTerm is not empty. Then I am creating a newFilters array from the selectedFiltersArray and updating the searchFiltersArray state with the new filters. Finally, I am enabling the Elasticsearch query.

But this is causing an indefinite loop of queries. Can someone help me identify the issue and suggest a fix?

Answer (score 0):

You could try out the following updated code:

```
const [isSearching, setIsSearching] = useState(false);

<SearchBox
  // other props
  onSearch={() => {
    if (!isSearching && selectedFiltersArray && selectedFiltersArray.length > 0 && searchTerm?.trim()) {
      setIsSearching(true);

      const newFilters = selectedFiltersArray.map((filterTerm: any) => ({
        [filterTerm.value]: { wildcard: `*${searchTerm}*` },
      }));

      setSearchFiltersArray((prev: any) => {
        const updatedFilters = [...prev];
        newFilters.forEach((newFilter: any) => {
          const key = Object.keys(newFilter)[0];
          const index = updatedFilters.findIndex((filterObj) => filterObj[key]);
          if (index === -1) {
            updatedFilters.push(newFilter);
          } else {
            updatedFilters[index] = newFilter;
          }
        });
        return updatedFilters;
      });

      setIsElasticSearchQueryEnabled(true);

      setIsSearching(false);
    }
  }}
  // other props
/>
```